# how make pysmp oids respone readable for human

Tags: python, python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

I create some smnp agent which will be use pysnmp to get response with OID.
How I can make response OID readable for human with pysnmp?

Example command generator:

```
    cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds =cmdGen.getCmd(
    cmdgen.UsmUserData('user','privKey','authKey'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('127.0.0.1', 161)),(1,3,6,1,2,1,1,1,0))

    #what I need:
    make_human_readble_OID(VarBinds)
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the *lookupNames* and/or *lookupValues* flags to getCmd() as shown [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v2c-with-mib-resolution.html). Keep in mind that human readability usually requires explicit use of MIBs. To use MIBs with pysnmp you would have to:

1. Convert MIBs from their native ASN.1 representation into pysnmp classes using build-pysnmp-mib tool (from pysnmp distribution)
2. Make pysnmp load and use those pysnmp-style MIBs by passing their location on the filesystems to MibVariable through .loadMibs() or .addMibSources() as shown [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v1-with-custom-mibs-location.html)